# shopify, making an ajax request from client side

Tags: ajax, shopify, liquid

I am making an app for shopify, that would allow costumers to send a message to a sites owner.
For this i have made a little server that would send the email on a post request.
Naturally, shopify would not let me do this. Instead, I am getting a cors, cross origin request issue. So I have created a private app, but they don't appear to provide me with the ability to make a post request to my server.

So I am looking into making a public unlisted app. But I am a bit burned out from my last attempt and am not in the mood to go off implementing oauth (for the first time) just to find out that I am still not getting the functionality that I need.

Can anyone please tell me what are the minimum requirements for me to be able to whitelist my server for ajax requests from the client side?.

Comment: In this form the question has nothing to do with Shopify. It points more towards the server gurus in StackOverflow. So it's best to update your tags and clarify what is your server running apache/ngix/etc...

Comment: I disagree, my question is about shopify's security protocols. since I cannot send a request to any server, no matter what its running on.

Comment: You don't have control over the Shopify server. Shopify is a closed platform, you need to enable CORS policy from your server, not Shopify. Shopify only requires to make HTTPS requests. If Shopify blocked outside requests a lot of Apps will not work. If you still believe that you need to update the Shopify server... well I can't help you there.